# Getting 503 Error on Google Dataflow - UNAVAILABLE

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I'm trying to run apache beam python pipeline on dataflow but immediately (10-15sec) after launching the job, it gets failed status.

The error on logs:

```
Failed to start the VM, launcher-2021030302333314603154945777358700, used for launching because of status code: UNAVAILABLE, reason: One or more operations had an error: 'operation-1614767615027-5bc9f6216a93c-7b50752f-842a8707': [UNAVAILABLE] 'HTTP_503'..
```

The error message gets cut short so I cannot dig into deeper. I believe I added all relevant permissions etc. but cant get it to work. Initial research suggests that it could be a backend issue or permissions issue?

In addition the same pipeline has worked in other projects.

Appreciate if someone can help me debug and fix.

Comment: The Google Cloud [error model](https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors#handling_errors) indicates that a 503 means the service is unavailable. If it works in other projects then Dataflow itself probably isn't down, so I would double check that you don't have any typos anywhere causing you to try to access a service that doesn't exist. Additionally, you shouldn't include your job ID on Stack Overflow, only Google Cloud support can access your jobs.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Let me know if you find something that would resolve this. Noted on the job id.

Comment: @DanielOliveira This seemed to be a region issue. My pipeline works fine when I change the region from europe-north1 to europe-west4. It was running in the latter in my other project but I discovered recently that Dataflow has expanded to north1 so I changed it. Maybe this is something your team can explore further?

Comment: Strange, Dataflow should be working just fine in that region. Sorry, I don't have any ideas why this might be happening.

Comment: No worries. I'll try again later if the new region works. As for now it works just fine in europe-west4.

Comment: Did you ever figure out the error? Getting the same message but switching regions hasn't resolved it.

Comment: Switching regions did work, just forgot to change the zone as well. Seems to be a region-related service error

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the region. I move the region from 'asia-southeast2' to 'us-central1' and it worked.